# Is it possible to show 1 column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, datagridview

Is it possible to only show the first column in a datagridview

for example

[image]

I only want to show REGION_ID and the rows under it.
Can someone help?

Comment: You mean only show the "rows" under Region_ID? How is the data grid defined in VS? Show your code for the data grid.

Comment: Don't define the column make it not visible in the definition.

Comment: @mybirthname it is not

Answer (score 3):

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["REGION_NAME"].Visible = false;
```

or

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false; //1 is the second column
```

Comment: What if you dont know the column name ?

Comment: @DaF you should try this out yourself. If you notice the tooltips it will accept EITHER a column name as a string OR the column index as an int.

Comment: Column index usually starts at 0.